# PHPStorm on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, ubuntu-15.10

I started PHPStorm (newest) on Ubuntu 15.10 few minutes before on the second monitor and now all it's really big (look at Screenshot). I'm using normal OpenJDK (not Sun). How I get it in normal size?

Monitor Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try with CTRL button + mouse week

Comment: No effect.. nothings happens

Comment: Please refrain from adding "urgent" to your questions - volunteers here will answer questions they find interesting at their leisure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use select :

**Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > Appearance > click on "Override default fonts by (not recommended)**

And select your font and your size (default is 12)

Comment: I have installed Gnome3 now and switch to them, this helps also on Unity. The problem was not PHPStorm, The problem was Unity. But thanks for help.